# Can I execute a parameter in a function in a class directly from a member of that class?

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
class LocalizedStrings{
    static let collect = NSLocalizedString("Collect %d coins", comment: "")
    class func returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(text: String, value: Int) -> String{
        return String.localizedStringWithFormat(text, value)
    }
 }
```

To get the variable collect with a format, I need to call:

`LocalizedString.collect.returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(text: collect, value: 100)`

There is two times `collect` there. I was wondering if it is possible to use `collect` directly as a parameter for 'text'. So it should look like this:

`LocalizedString.collect.returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(value: 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make custom `LocalizedString` struct .

```
struct LocalizedString {
    var text: String
    var comment: String
}

extension LocalizedString {
    func returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(value: Int) -> String {
        let localizedStringOrigin = NSLocalizedString(text, comment: comment)
        return String.localizedStringWithFormat(localizedStringOrigin, value)
    }
}
```

Then your localized strings storage:

```
struct LocalizedStrings{
    static let collect = LocalizedString(text: "Collect %d coins", comment: "")
    static let cook = LocalizedString(text: "Make %d cookies", comment: "")
}
```

Usage:

```
LocalizedStrings.collect.returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(value: 100)
LocalizedStrings.cook.returnLocalizedStringWithFormat(value: 100)
```

Prints:

```
"Collect 100 coins"
"Make 100 cookies"
```

__

**P.S. Technically speaking**, you can simply extend `String`:

```
extension String {
    func localized(value: Int) -> String {
        return String.localizedStringWithFormat(self, value)
    }
}
```

And whenever you have such class:

```
class LocalizedStrings{
    static let collect = NSLocalizedString("Collect %d coins", comment: "")
}
```

Simply call:

```
LocalizedStrings.collect.localized(value: 100)
```

But this is definitely bad design, because `localized` becomes available to all strings, both localizable (returned by `NSLocalizedString(..)`) and not. Hence a better practice is a separate entity with an encapsulated method.

Comment: There can be more strings so providing a default value would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your goal is to simplify your work with UI localization. If so, I strongly recommend you to use [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen). Also it applies to assets, colors, fonts, storyboards.

There are multiple benefits in using this:

- Avoid any typo you could have when using a `String`
- Free auto-completion
- Avoid the risk to use an non-existing asset name

All this will be ensured by the compiler.